# Show $f(z)=2u\left( \frac z2, \frac{-iz}{2}\right ) + \text{constant} $ if $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is an analytic function

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose  $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$  be an analytic function. Show that

$ \displaystyle (a)\;  f(z)=2u\left(\frac z2,\frac{-iz}{2} \right ) +\text{ constant} \\(b) \; f(z)=2iv\left(\frac z2,\frac{iz}{2} \right )+\text{ constant}$

Comment: Sry but why you say "If $f(z)=u(x+y)+i v(x,y)$", using $z=x+iy$ one can always express as $f(z)=\Re(f(z))+\Im(f(z))=\Re(f(x+iy)) + \Im(f(x+iy))$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis the question was written that way, "Let $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y) $  ..." any idea on the problem part??

Comment: The question as stated makes no sense. $u$ and $v$ are functions of two real variables, you can't feed them complex numbers.

Comment: It reminds me a bit of the equivalent definition of complex differentiable ...

Comment: @JavierBadia sorry, i have forgotten something.

Comment: My complaint still stands. $u$ and $v$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, you can't give them complex numbers as arguments.

Comment: Yes, there is a real theorem here.  (But Mula has not stated it yet.)  Try $f(z) = z^2$, $u(x,y) = x^2-y^2$, and $v(x,y)=2xy$.  Then it makes sense to plug in complex numbers in $u$ and $v$, and the claimed formula works!

Comment: One way to make sense of this is: If $f$ is complex analytic, then $u$, $v$ are real analytic and if you extend $u$ and $v$'s definition to the complex plane in the obvious manner, does $f$  and the extended $u$, $v$ satisfy the stated conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part (a) of your question is discussed in Ahlfors' "Complex Analysis" text on page 27. He warns ahead of the discussion that it is *purely formal* and shouldn't be used to prove anything.

First of all, you need to consider the formal derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right), \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right). $$
Note that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are simply $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$.

Take any analytic function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, Its conjugate $\overline{f(z)}$ satisfies $\frac{\partial \overline{f(z)}}{\partial z}=0$. *Formally* this means that $\overline{f(z)}$ is a function of $\bar{z}$ only; Denote this function by $\bar{f}(\bar{z})$. Thus we have 
$$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2} \left( f(x+iy)+\bar{f}(x-iy) \right).$$
Once again, we *formally* interpret this identity for *complex* $x,y$. We can therefore plug in $x=\frac{z}{2},y=\frac{z}{2i}$, and obtain:
$$u \left(\frac{z}{2},\frac{z}{2i} \right)=\frac{1}{2} \left( f(z)+\bar{f}(0) \right), $$ which is upon rearrangement $$f(z)=2u \left(\frac{z}{2},\frac{z}{2i} \right)+\text{const}. $$
Part (b) can be done similarly.

The greatest issue here is plugging in complex values for $x,y$. In general it cannot be done, but for simple functions, such as polynomials, everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need some hypotheses?  For example
$$
|z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + i\cdot 0;\quad f(z):=|z|, u(x,y) := \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, v(x,y):=0
$$
but
$$
2u(z/2,-iz/2) = 2\sqrt{\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-iz}{2}\right)^2}
=2\sqrt{\frac{z^2-z^2}{4}}=0
$$

Comment: could you recheck, I had been missing something 
+ c o n s t a n t  was at the end

Comment: @GEdgar, the function you defined is not holomorphic so it doesn't even apply.

Comment: The condition "analytic" was added just 4 hours ago.  That is what I meant by "perhaps you need some hypotheses".