# Finding a holomorphic function when knowing real part

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on the following problem and would appreciate help to proceed.

Problem:

Find a holomorphic function $f(x, y)$ such that $Re(f(x, y)) = x^3 − 3xy^2 + 12xy − 12x$
and write the function as a degree 3 polynomial in the
variable $z = x + iy$.

Preliminary ideas:

- Write the function as $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, where $z = x + iy$, so that i add the imaginary part
- Check if the partial derivatives satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations.
- To make a 3rd degree polynomial, insert z = x + iy in whatever holomorphic function I find

Comment: Find $v$ using Cauchy Riemann equations. Examples can be found easily in books on Complex Analysis.

Comment: [Oppenheim's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/344702): $f(z)=2u(\frac{z}{2},\,\frac{z}{2i})+\text{constant}$.

Comment: So, i find v to be x^3 - 6xy by taking partial derivative. Should i then set this equal to du/dx? And this is my holomorphic function? I think I don't get the overall logic: why and how to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations

Comment: $f(x,y)$ should be a polynomial of third degree. Inspect the real and imaginary parts of $z^3$, $z^2$ and $z$ and cook up a solution.